# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

When I try to login I get an error:

**SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

parametrs.yml:

This file is auto-generated during the composer install

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: sgce
    database_user: root
    database_password: mikem
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

My OS is Debian

Thanks for your help.

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
#skip-grant-tables
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
bind-address        = 10.1.4.3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to your mysql configuration.
According to this error you are trying to connect with the user 'root' to the database host 'localhost' on a database namend 'sgce' without being granted access rights.

Presuming you did not configure your mysql instance. Log in as root user and to the folloing:

```
CREATE DATABASE sgce;

CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mikem';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sgce. * TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Also add your database_port in the parameters.yml.
By default mysql listens on 3306:

```
database_port: 3306
```

Comment: did you try directly on your terminal?
mysql -u roo -p ?

Comment: did you add the port? where is your db running at?

Comment: yes i wrote the port 3306, what do you advise me, but i'm still not can logging

Comment: is your db on the same server as your symfony app?

Comment: Could also be the my.cnf setting for `bind-address`. By default it points to 127.0.0.1, so maybe try `database_host: 127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I post my my.conf above

Comment: "Could also be the my.cnf setting for bind-address. By default it points to 127.0.0.1, so maybe try database_host: 127.0.0.1"
i am still cant login :(

Answer (score 5):

`database_password: password` would between quotes: " or '.

like so:

`database_password: "password"`

Answer (score 3):

This basically means that either your username incorrect or your password is incorrect. Please countercheck and make sure you are using the correct password

Comment: Is this answer supposed to be attached to this question? I see no mention of bootstrap in the question, and no explanation in the answer about why the clearing the cache might help with a SQL error.

Answer (score 1):

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

add this in your code

Answer (score 1):

I'm Using Xampp and Laravel 5.8 in Windows 10, and i've been like this before. When i got this problem, My XAMPP is no have Password
Then I tried to delete some codes in 
`config>database.php`

```
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
```

And in `.env`

```
DB_PASSWORD=SECRET
```

the Problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

write direct password into config>database.php

> 'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '')

Change to

> 'password'  =>  'your password',