# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `rooms` order by `order_by` asc)

Tags: php, laravel, server

my code run fine in localhost but when i uploaded it on the serve following error show

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (1045)
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `rooms` order by `order_by` asc)
Previous exceptions
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (1045)

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:tT9jGFWVeBX5uLy/CVZbs8k+RNGBpMyJ526xfRv3DKQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=janatapa_shre
DB_USERNAME=janatapa_shre
DB_PASSWORD=Shre@123

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

though i have changed the database name , user and password  in .env file it still says
**"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"** 
which was my localhost password and user name''

I couldnt even clear my cache

while i was try to use following code on server

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
```

the following error was shown on the terminal

[In Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas
  sword: NO) (SQL: select * from `rooms` order by `order_by` asc)

In Connector.php line 70:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas
  sword: NO) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHAWa.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594962/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password)

Comment: Try change APP_ENV to production and see what's happens.

Comment: it isnt working. though i have changed the password to Shre@123 and user name to janatapa_shre error is showing SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). I couldnt event clear the cache

Answer (score 9):

I also faced this issue, every thing is fine your DB_USERNAME or DB_PASSWORD, if you your password string contains # (for eg. Test123#) "feature"of 5.8 or above it treat # as comment delimiter, so rewrite your password as DB_PASSWORD='Test123#' and its works.
it work for me.

Comment: Same here, I was perplexed! For more details about this check out the docs:https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade

Answer (score 3):

It's due to caching. so delete cache file 'config.php' from bootstrap/cache/config.php . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I also was facing the same problem! 
 it's due to password string format.
all passwords string contains # (for eg. Test123#. test@#, test123$$) must be between quotations
laravel 5.8 above need password to be in a quat 
`DB_PASSWORD='Test123#'`
then run `php artisan config:cache` 
 then migrate DB through `php artisan migrate`
it works for me just fine

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error.
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'niyo'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I found that I did not create user called `niyo` and grant to him all privileges. I configured it in *user accounts* section of `PhpMyAdmin` interface.

#### .env file sample

```php
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=oneagentdb
DB_USERNAME=niyo
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make changes in .dev you must to this after this changes
`php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 0):

If everything is ok with the .env file, and you set username and password correct. Then in your project's path open the terminal and use this command,

> php artisan cache:clear

I hope it'll be helpful.