# Laravel: Access denied for user using No password

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I uploaded my laravel project to my shared server and when I try to connect to it through Postman and register a new user but it gives me the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'stylmyvz_haraj'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = bella@alexa.com limit 1) in file /home/stylmyvz/cars.styleshopeg.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 671
```

I am wondering why it gives me that Access denied (using password: NO) although I set the password in .env file

I run 'php artisan serve' on the server but I receive this error:

```
ErrorException

  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php:43
    39|      * @throws \Exception
    40|      */
    41|     public function handle()
    42|     {
  > 43|         chdir(public_path());
    44|
    45|         $this->line("Laravel development server started: http://{$this->host()}:{$this->port()}");
    46|
    47|         passthru($this->serverCommand(), $status);

      +15 vendor frames
  16  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Any solution for it?

Comment: Try `php artisan config:clear` to clear a cached config file (or `php artisan config:cache` to clear _and_ cache it)

Comment: I try using it but it did not work still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

If you've updated your password in the .env file and haven't restarted the server it might not be seeing the changes in the .env file. If you're using `php artisan serve` just kill that command and run it again. If you're using a different web server, do whatever you need to do to restart the web server and see if that helps.

Edit:

Learning that you're on a shared host, try running `php artisan config:cache` and see if that helps. Side note: You cannot run `php artisan serve` because you're already running a server on the shared host.

Another Possibility:

It's possible that the user `'stylmyvz_haraj'@'localhost'` is not actually on the database listed in the .env file. You might need to check your shared host management area to ensure the user and password are set properly on the appropriate database.

Comment: I am not using Heroku or service like it to deploy my project on it, I am just using my shared hosting server.. is there a way to restart an online server ?? note: it is already updated  the username and database name but did not update the password although I typed them all together

Comment: I managed to run php artisan serve on the server and I received an error updated in the subject.. can you take a look at it please?

Comment: @AlexAli I've updated my answer above in light of your new information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this post here:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61291483/4540284)

the problem was that password was starting with # which it was considered as a comment so I put the password like this: '#fhh344+9f' and it finally worked